# web server behind NAT cannot be accessed by the same network using NAT router IP or domain

Tags: iptables, web-server, nat, port-forwarding

I have 1 **host server** as NAT server, it has public domain name `example.com` tied to its public IP address `PUB_IP_ADD`.

I have another **web server** behind NAT with IP address `192.168.1.100` and port forwarding rules is done on the **host server**:

> -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:80

I have some **other servers** behind NAT with fixed ip address range `192.168.1.101-110` and the `masquerade` rules are done for the whole `192.168.1.0/24` range:

> -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE

the above rules can let my servers behind NAT access internet. (download and ping public ips).

My web page can be accessed from the internet by visiting `example.com` but cannot be accessed from inside the NAT network in those `192.168.1.0/24` by using the same domain name or **host server** ip address.

I wonder, why the web server behind the NAT firewall cannot be accessed by its peers by using NAT server domain name or IP?

Do I need to add `SNAT` rules specifically to the **web server** and remove the `masquerade` line?

Comment: so you cannot access web server locally on `192.168.1.100`?

Comment: I cannot access web server from 192.168.1.101 via example. com

Comment: probably because you do not have `DNS` configured for that domain name for local network. you could even add an entry to /etc/hosts file such as `192.168.1.100  example.com` which would resolve domain to ip for that computer

Comment: The DNS is set correctly, the domain is register under godaddy, i can access my other godaddy domain names from behind nat as well.

Comment: looks like a hairpin NAT problem as asked and answered here http://serverfault.com/questions/205040/accessing-the-dnatted-webserver-from-inside-the-lan

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use SNAT if you use static IPs as MASQUERADE suffers a penalty as it needs to get the IP address from the network interface.

Also, if you are testing from the firewall computer, it will try to access its own web server instead of the dedicated web server. We need to place a rule in the OUTPUT chain to deal with this case:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $INET_IP --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $HTTP_IP
```